# propTypes warning in Electron app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to deal with the new warning about needing to include the prop-types package in NPM programs. My app is an electron app.

I think I am following the migration strategy from the React folks: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html

react version-15.4.2, prop-types version 15.5.8, react-dom 15.42.2

However, I am still getting the warning after adding the prop-types package.

This is the component (Dashboard.jsx)

```
const React = require('react')
const { Component } = require('react')
const {} = require('react-bootstrap')
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { App, Title, Section, Header, Footer, Columns, Box, Button } from 'grommet'


export const Page = props => (
  <App>
    <Title>Dashboard Version 1.0, Node version: xxx</Title>
    <Section>Status Section
      <p>Status: {props.serverState}</p>
    </Section>
    <Section >{/*  colorIndex='neutral-1' */ }
      <Header>Controls</Header>
      <Columns>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='Install' onClick={props.installAct}></Button>
        </Box>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='UnInstall' onClick={props.uninstallAct}></Button>
        </Box>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='Start' onClick={props.startAct}></Button>
        </Box>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='Stop' onClick={props.stopAct}></Button>
        </Box>
      </Columns>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Header>Config</Header>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Header>Cleanup</Header>
    </Section>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </App>
)
```

And this is the main render process (dash.js)

```
const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron')
const { createStore } = require('redux')
const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
const { Page } = require('../jsxo/Dashboard.js')
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
const PropTypes = require('prop-types')
const Immutable = require('immutable')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", render)



const page = React.createElement(Page, { serverState: 'UP', 
        installAct: () => alert('install'),
        uninstallAct: () => alert('uninstall'),
        startAct: () => alert('start'),
        stopAct: () => alert('stop') })


function render() {
    ReactDOM.render(page, document.getElementById('page'))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `grommet` which hasn't been updated to the new `react` version yet, therefore you will be getting warnings from this library because it uses the deprecated `PropTypes` from `react` module.

There is nothing you can do until your dependencies are updated, too.

Note this has been already [reported](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/issues/1303) and there is a pull request open.

Comment: thanks, once they have done that, do I still need to import the prop-types myself? or is my code "good to go" for version 16 @Sulthan

Comment: You need to import `prop-types` only if you are using them. If you are not defining `propTypes` for your components (e.g. if you are using `flow` instead), there is no need to import them.

Comment: By the way, `react-bootstrap` has fixed the same issue just today.